# best practices for saving user ids in Redis

Tags: redis, nosql

I'm learning Redis and I would like to know if using INCR to generate unique user ids is a good pratice or, if  it's not,  what would be some possible scenarios where it could lead to problems. Note: this question assumes there's no other database involved

The other approach I can think of is generating a random uuid() and using that, but in case both approaches are aceptable, what would be the trade offs?

Here's some example code I found online that does this:

```
 uid = db.incr("users:enum")
 pipe = db.pipeline()
 pipe.set("users:%s:uid" % username, uid)
 pipe.set("users:%s" % username, password_hash) 
 pipe.sadd("users", username)
```

Comment: The trade-off is minimal, but using something like `uuid()` might be faster since it depends on things like process ID, timestamp, etc. that your process already "knows", without the need of going through an operation to Redis which may result in minor latency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a valid approach since INCR is atomic. In fact there is a [tutorial](http://redis.io/topics/twitter-clone) on redis.io which follows this method.